# How to trigger a script when changing of slide in ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ion-slides

I'm writing an application in Ionic & Angular.
I'm using the ion-slides component and I would like to launch a script to recalculate the full amounts at each change of slide...
Could you please explain to me how to do it?
Is there a generic event?
Thanks for reading so far.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it by myself:

in the html:

```
   <ion-slides (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged()">
```

in the ts:

```
  slideChanged()
  {
    console.log('Slide changed');
}
```